# Не работает modx ошибка - Site temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, mysql, modx

Не работает modx ошибка - Site temporarily unavailable.
В логах выявил следующею ошибку -

```
[2017-12-06 01:10:35] (ERROR @ /home/vdpoosetia/vdpo-osetia.ru/core/xpdo/om/xpdoobject.class.php : 240) Error 42S22 executing statement: 
Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'modSystemSetting.key' in 'field list'
)

[2017-12-06 01:10:35] (ERROR @ /home/vdpoosetia/vdpo-osetia.ru/core/xpdo/om/xpdoobject.class.php : 240) Error 42S22 executing statement: 
Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'modSystemSetting.key' in 'field list'
)

[2017-12-06 01:10:35] (FATAL) Could not load core MODX configuration!
```

Comment: вы не забыли написать, что например, обновляли версию движка?

Comment: Я не обновлял движок, восстанавливал сайт, установил по новой сайт и залил базу

Comment: @Alan.Sh Вам удалось решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

После обновления, Modx ломает пути к файлам - делает их абсолютными. 
Проверьте пути в этих файлах:

```
config.core.php - define('MODX_CORE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/core/');
manager/config.core.php - define('MODX_CORE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/core/');
connectors/config.core.php - define('MODX_CORE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/core/');
```

Вот такие записи должны быть в первых строчках этих файлов
Либо проверьте параметры подключения к базе. При неправильных данных modx выдает такую надпись. Но 90% что проблема в путях судя по

> Could not load core MODX configuration!

Answer (score 0):

Переустановите modx, точнее залейте папку setup и нажмите обновить.

Comment: После выбора способа обновление, опять кидает на ошибку Site temporarily unavailable

Comment: нужно очистить папочку cache в папке core

Comment: все равно тоже самое